# Composite component to produce output from multiple input components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I am creating a composite component that consists of a selectOneListbox and several selectManyCheckboxes. The user will be presented with these inputs and once they have made their selections, the values of these components will be combined to produce a formatted String output which is the "value" of this composite component. Currently I have the composite component looking something like below, how do I bind the formatted output string to the value of the composite component when the user submits the form?

I am using Primefaces along with JSF but I think the solution (whatever it is) should be able to apply to either.

Composite Component:

The formatted string is displayed to the user as the user makes the selections on the screen. This is done via ajax updates to the outputText `formattedOutput`. I added a hidden input at the bottom of the CC. The idea is that I'll use javascript to set the new value of `formattedOutput` whenever it gets updated, but I'm not sure how.

```
<composite:interface>
     <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

  <div id="#{cc.clientId}">

    <h:outputLabel value="Current Formatted Output" for="formattedOutput"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{backingBean.formattedOutput}" id="formattedOutput"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="First Input" for="input1"/>
    <p:selectOneListbox id="input1" required="true" value="#{backingBean.input1}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{staticControlsData.options1}"/>
         <p:ajax event="change" update="formattedOutput" listener="#{backingBean.buildFormattedOutputString}"/>
    </p:selectOneListbox>

    <p:outputLabel value="Second Input" for="input2"/>
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="input2" value="#{backingBean.input2}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{staticControlsData.options2}"/>
        <p:ajax event="change" update="formattedOutput" listener="#{backingBean.buildFormattedOutputString}"/>
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>

    <h:inputHidden id="hiddenValue" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
  </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

This is how I want the composite component to be used:

```
<h:form>
    <my:component value="#{anotherBean.aField}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Save" />
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script to composite component:

```
function ajaxUpdateComplete(){
    var formattedOutputElement = document.getElementById("#{cc.clientId}" + ":formattedOutput");
    var updatedValue = formattedOutputElement.innerHTML;//we are taking innerHTML because outputText renders as span and has no "value"
    var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('#{cc.clientId}' + ":hiddenValue");
    hiddenElement.value = updatedValue;
}
```

And to your two `<p:ajax>` add `oncomplete="ajaxUpdateComplete"`

So, after each ajax call value of hidden field will be updated and ready to be post with form, which your composite component lays in

Comment: Whilst this may work, this is not the "legal" way to set the value of a composite component. You're  basically completely missing the point of a composite component this way.